# Rookie question for idb file

Tags: mariadb

A rookie question here.

I have read that idb files in mariadb are used for restoring a table.
Does that means that they hold records of deletion too?

I 'd like to know that, if I delete a row from a table, this deletion is going to be written to the idb file and I can restore it later ?

thanks.

Comment: Not at all. I'm glad you asked rather than believing the [fc]rud that's written. See [overview of backup mechanisms](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/backup-and-restore-overview/), [flashback](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/flashback/), and if your want to keep records of a table but still appear deleted, look at [system versioned tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/).

Comment: Thank you,  @danblack write this as an answer so I can accept it as solution.

Comment: *I have read that idb files in mariadb are used for restoring a table.* Have you read how difficult this process is? Have you read that there is no any guarantee? *if I delete a row from a table, this deletion is going to be written to the idb file* True. *I can restore it later ?* 50/50. Like for the file deleted from the disk... and this process is more difficult than restoring old data styate with IDB file replacing which is difficult itself. Backup is preferred method.

Comment: @Akina so you tell me that if a delete a row the row still exists in  idb file. Is that a reason why this file is not shrinking its size even if a delete a lot rows from the table?

Comment: *you tell me that if a delete a row the row still exists in idb file.* Yes, the probability is high. But not guaranteed neverhteless. *Is that a reason why this file is not shrinking its size even if a delete a lot rows from the table?* No. The reason is simple - the server only cares about the data. It absolutely does not care what happens to the disk space.

Answer (score 1):

"Point-in-time" recovery will reset the database to a particular time in the past.  This can be done with aid of the "binlog".

Undoing a single `DELETE` can be done in code if you discover it before the end of the "transaction" -- `ROLLBACK` the transaction instead of doing a `COMMIT`.  All modifications done by the transaction will be undone.

While the contents of the row 'before' the delete is stored somewhere, it is *not* otherwise available for the "undo" that you described.

Some programmers use a "soft delete" wherein they create an extra column (`is deleted` = 0 or 1; `active` = 0 or 1; `deleted_at` = NULL or a datetime) to indicate that the row is "deleted" without actually removing the data.  The drawback is the extra code to test that column (most of the time) and the potential slowdown due to that test.  And this approach requires planning ahead.

And MariaDB (but not MySQL) has "versioning" -- see danblack's Comment.

(Re your question to Akina)  The .ibd (and ibdata1) files never shrink.  The code to effect a shrinkage is not worth the horrific programming effort it would take to.  And, anyway, you are quite likely to Insert a new row that will consume that freed-up space; so why bother.  Yes, there is an administrator command you can run to shrink the file, but, again, Inserts will then make it grow again.  If you need to Delete most or all of a table, there are [better ways](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig) to do that.